# Deleting Elements in Array equal to a value

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to make a code that removes all the elements from the array that are equal to a given value. For example an `array =  [hi, hello, hi, bye]`  `value = hi`, it would given an output `hello bye`

Here's my code:

```java
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<stringArr.length; 
        if(stringArr[i].equals(value)){
            count--;
            for(int j= i; j<stringArr.length-1; j++){
                stringArr[j] = stringArr[j+1];
            }
            i--;
    }
}
```

Problem is instead of the expected output as: `hello bye`
It gives an output of:

```
hello hi bye bye
```

Comment: What is the `count` variable for? Why are you manipulating `i` in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try Java stream api:

```java
String value = "hi";
String[] stringArr = new String[] {"hi", "hello", "hi", "bye"};
String[] results = Arrays.stream(stringArr)
                .filter(it -> !it.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are shifting the values left but not decrementing the length of the array in the outer for.

Assign `stringArr.length` to `count` and use it in the for.

Answer (score 0):

Trading memory for speed, you could create a new array of the same length and only add in the first occurrence of what you want.

```
    String[] removeEqual(String[]array,String val){
       boolean found =false;
       String[]out=new String[array.length];
       int count=0;
       for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
          if(array[i].equals(val)){
             if(!found){
                out[count++]=val;
                found=true;
             }
             else out[count++]=val;                     
          }
       }
       return Arrays.copyOf(out, count);
    }
```

You may like to consider separate functions for separate conditions such as removeLessThan and removeGreaterThan to keep it functionally coherent.

Answer (score 0):

An array has a fixed size that cannot be changed. Hence your result cannot be a two element array when you start with a four element array. If you want the result to be a two element array, then you will need to create a second array. If, however, you want the result to stay in the original array, then I suggest setting the excess array elements to null. The following code demonstrates.

```java
String[] stringArr = {"hi", "hello", "hi", "bye"};
String condition = "==";
String value = "hi";
int count = stringArr.length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (condition.equals("==")) {
        if (stringArr[i].equals(value)) {
            count--;
            for (int j = i; j < stringArr.length - 1; j++) {
                stringArr[j] = stringArr[j + 1];
            }
            stringArr[stringArr.length - 1] = null;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(stringArr));
```

The above code prints the following:

```
[hello, bye, null, null]
```

### EDIT

As requested, below code creates a new array that only contains the requested elements, i.e. the ones that were not removed from the original array.

```java
String[] stringArr = {"hi", "hello", "hi", "bye"};
String condition = "==";
String value = "hi";
String[] temp = new String[stringArr.length];
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++) {
    if (condition.equals("==")) {
        if (!stringArr[i].equals(value)) {
            temp[count++] = stringArr[i];
        }
    }
}
String[] result = new String[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result[i] = temp[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

The above code prints the following:

```
[hello, bye]
```

In other words, `result` is a two element array.

Note that I assume that you only want to do array manipulation and you don't want to use classes in the JDK that most of the other answers have used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to do any manipulation to the original array, create a new one. Recycling is good for the planet, but may be very harmful in code. So if you want to stick to the Arrays only, then create a new array with and add all elements you want into the new array, but I think you can do better. Your approach is very "C" like, this is Java, you have a lot of better tools, than arrays.

One of them are streams and lambdas like this

```
@Test
public void example_lambdas() {
    String[] array = {"hi", "hello", "hi", "bye"};
    String[] result = Arrays.stream(array).filter(element -> !"hi".equals(element)).toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Another option is to use list

```
@Test
public void example_list() {
    String[] array = {"hi", "hello", "hi", "bye"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
    Set<String> toBeRemoved = Collections.singleton("hi");
    list.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
    String[] result = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```